# If I'm creating 10 compute instances through a script on GCP, will those instances get created sequentially or parallely?

Tags: shell, google-cloud-platform, scripting, sh

I'm trying to create 10 instances on GCP console through a shell script. The allocation of resources to these instances is done parallelly(All starts getting created at once) or sequentially (Creation of Instance#2 starts when resources have been allocated to Instance#1)?

Comment: If we look at the gcloud command, we see an async flag which specifies that the instance creation can occur in the background without waiting for it to complete.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create#--async

Answer (score 3):

The Google Cloud Console does not support shell scripts.

If you mean that you are using the SDK CLI `gcloud`, you have the option `--async` to not wait for the API command to complete. Otherwise, the commands run one at a time.

The shell itself waits for the program to complete, which does not mean that the instance has been created. There is some overhead in launching gcloud. I do not recommend using the `&` to launch multiple `gcloud` commands at the same time.

One last item, check your quota to make sure that you can launch 10 instances in the zone(s) that you desire.

[Compute Engine Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas)

Comment: you can also use HTTP post request to create your VM. This behavior is the same as the --async mentioned by @Johnhanley.